# CKEditor break <div>

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

CKEditor works great. There is just minor thing which I would like to improve

We have message system which uses CKEditor. The original (old) text is in a  with a vertical blue line. See the screenshot:

[image]

I would like to break the `<div>`.

Up to now I found no way to break it.

In my case a RETURN key should break the `<div>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can config the enter key with the following modes:

- ENTER_P – new `<p>` paragraphs are created;
- ENTER_BR – lines are broken with `<br>` elements;
- ENTER_DIV – new `<div>` blocks are created.

---

So in your case, to break a div:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea_id', {
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV
});
```

Here are the docs for [ENTER_BR](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-ENTER_BR)

Answer (score 4):

If setting `enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV` doesn't work for you, another solution is to capture the `enter` keypress and manually break the `div` by:

1) inserting a closing `</div>` tag to split the blue line `div`, creating the upper half.

2) inserting a new tag `<div class="novertline">` which opens a div without a vertical line - This is the break.

3) insert a closing `</div>`

4) insert another  which makes the bottom half of the split text retain its vertical line.

Because `insertHtml` doesn't allow splitting a div, I used `insertText` with a flag to subsequently replace with my `html`.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.textarea.on( 'key', function (evt) {
    if (evt.data.keyCode == 13){
        CKEDITOR.instances.textarea.insertText('SOME FLAG');
        var data = CKEDITOR.instances.textarea.getData();
        data = data.replace('SOME FLAG', '</div><div class="novertline"></div><div class="vertline">');
        CKEDITOR.instances.textarea.setData(data);
    }
});
```

In my `ckeditor.css` file, I added my two classes - but you obviously already have your equivalent `div` class which is creating the blue line:

```
.vertline {
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    height: 100%;
}
.novertline {
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-left: none;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will need to be customized to your situation. However, it does break the `div` as you require.